# ASP.net MVC unable to get value back from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

in my ASP.net MVC application, I have a button that call a controller action which takes longer (>60 mins) to complete. To keep my session alive I am using setInterval function.

reference: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

view looks like:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                        {
                            settings.Name = "LoadData";
                            settings.Text = "Load Data";
                            settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ OnButtonClick(s, e, '{0}', '{1}'); }}", Url.Action("Start", "ImportData", null), Url.Action("alive", "ImportData", null));
                            settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                        }).GetHtml()
```

my OnButtonClick Function looks:

```
function OnButtonClick(s, e, startUrl, progressUrl) {
    //debugger;
    StartActionOnServer(startUrl);
    setInterval(keepalive, 600000); //every 10 minutes. 
}
```

Keep Alive looks like:

```
function keepalive()
{
    console.log("I am alive");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ImportData/alive',
        dataType: "text",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            debugger;
            console.log("pinging");
        },
        Error: function (xhr) {
            debugger;
            alert(xhr)
        },
        });
 }
```

my issue is that code is not hitting my Controller function, as result I never get result back in my success block.

```
success: function (msg) {
            debugger;
            console.log("pinging");
        },
```

Controller action function:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult alive()
    {
        var result = "Still Alive";
        return Content(result);
    }
```

Instead of me hardcoding:  console.log("I am alive"); I would like Controller to return this.

my console.log looks like attached screeshot

[image]

Any idea how to get value from Controller ?What am I doing wrong here. 
Thanks.

Comment: do you see network tab in console to see whether url path is correct ?

Comment: `"I never get result back in my success block"` - Then what *do* you get back?  Note that you may be ignoring errors because you mis-typed the `error` property (you have `Error`).  What's the actual response from the server in your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: Is this MVC or Web-Api?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you receive a `JsonResult` rather than `Content` back?

Comment: Or change the content type to text instead?  If  you change it to text, the response (in msg variable on callback) should be the content returned from the controller.

Comment: oh shoot, changing dataType: "text"  solved it.  I see i added it twice:
dataType: "text",
dataType: 'json',

Comment: I take it back. keepalive  - /ImportData/alive does return the value but it is called after  StartActionOnServer is complete. My log looks like:
I am alive
I am alive
I am alive
I am alive
pinging
I am done

instead of 
I am alive
pinging
I am alive
pinging
I am alive
pinging
I am alive
pinging
I am done

"I am done" is returned from StartActionOnServer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
function keepalive()
{
    console.log("I am alive");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ImportData/alive',
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "text",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        Error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr)
        },
    });
 }
```